# Automapper fails when projecting IQueryable<object> when object has a collection property

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

So, here's my situation. I've got a my two classes:

```
class FromClass
{
    public string[] Foo { get; set; }
}

class ToClass
{
    public string[] Foo { get; set; }
}
```

The classes have properties which are arrays. They could be `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`, I get the same result in any of those cases.

I try to map from one to the other using the `AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create a "From" object
        string[] anArray = new string[] { "a", "b" };
        FromClass anObject = new FromClass() { Foo = anArray };

        // make a queryable set that includes the "From" object
        IQueryable<FromClass> queryableObjects = (new FromClass[] { anObject }).AsQueryable();

        // set up AutoMapper
        Mapper.CreateMap<FromClass, ToClass>();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        // test plain mapping
        IQueryable<ToClass> test1 = queryableObjects.Select(o => Mapper.Map<FromClass, ToClass>(o));
            // success!

        // test queryable extensions
        IQueryable<ToClass> test2 = queryableObjects.Project().To<ToClass>();
            // InvalidOperationException: "Sequence contains no elements"

    }
}
```

Why does test2 throw an `InvalidOperationException`? If I make the type of `Foo` something that's not a collection, e.g. a `string` or some other class -- then everything works perfectly.

Am I doing something wrong? Not understanding something? Or have I hit a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say: this is a bug: see [Github Issue 159](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/159).

The AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions uses `Mapper.CreateMapExpression` internally so if you write:

```
var expression = Mapper.CreateMapExpression<FromClass, ToClass>();
```

It will also fail with the same exception.

It seems `Mapper.CreateMapExpression` currently does not support:

- generic collections of value types e.g. `List<string>` etc.
- arrays of complex types or value types e.g `string[]`, `Bar[]` etc.

But if you make your `Foo` to `List<Item>` it can work:

```
public class FromClass
{
    public List<Item> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class ToClass
{
    public List<Item> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

var list =  new List<Item> { new Item{ Bar = "a"}, new Item() { Bar= "b" }};
FromClass anObject = new FromClass() { Foo = list };
var queryableObjects = (new FromClass[] { anObject }).AsQueryable();
Mapper.CreateMap<FromClass, ToClass>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, Item>();
var test2 = queryableObjects.Project().To<ToClass>().ToArray();
```

You can comment on the above mentioned issue or create a new one with your code (it's a quite good repro of the bug)

Comment: Ah, that's exactly the issue. Thank you. Using a complex type does indeed work (as long as there's that explicit `CreateMap<Item,Item>()` call there, which doesn't seem to be needed in the plain mapping case).

Comment: I've commented on [the github issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/159).  In the meantime, the workaround of using lists of complex types works just fine. Cheers again!

Comment: Hm. The github issue has been closed. Seems like a "WontFix" unfortunately.