# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping error in Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am using an `Automapper` to map one model to second model which has some rows with the same name as the first model. I am getting this inner exception

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>      Mapping types:
>      Bed -> Bed
>      Model1.Bed -> Model2.Bed

This is the condensed version of the code.

Model 1

```
public class Model1
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bed> Beds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bed> Beds1 { get; set; }
    public string Status {get; set;}
    public string Notes {get; set;} 
}
public class Model2
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bed> Beds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bed> Beds1 { get; set; }
}


public class Bed
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }        
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping :

```
 MapperConfiguration config = null;
 config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<Model1, Model2>(); });           
 IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
 var dest = mapper.Map<Model1, Model2>(update);
```

update is an instance of Model1. Am I missing something? Should I do something with regards to the Bed class mapping even though both reference the same method?
Also is there a way to copy data from one model to another in this scenario other than manually doing it or using Automapper?

EDIT 1:
I am sure the error is from that mapping. I removed it and all the other fields were fine and there was no exception. But I am not sure how I should do the Bed -> Bed binding.

EDIT 2:[This link](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/159) seems to have the same issue and they say it's a possible bug and [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10292384/4761773) seems to have the answer although I am not sure how I can adapt it to my situation.

Comment: Have you tried creating a mapping for Bed -> Bed?  Seems like it shouldn't be necessary but perhaps worth a shot...

Comment: @Zoop How do I go about doing it? What part of my code do I add it?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I'd try adding a second line in between the curly braces {}.  In other words:

config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{ 
    cfg.CreateMap<Model1, Model2>(); 
    cfg.CreateMap<Bed, Bed>(); 
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like auto mapper is having trouble determining how to map Bed. I would try the following:

```
config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { 

     cfg.CreateMap<Model1, Model2>(); 
     cfg.CreateMap<Bed, Bed>();

});
```

Although it seems odd that would be necessary...

Comment: That was the missing issue. I am not sure why it was needed but it seem to resolve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, seems strange but I'm glad it worked.  Good luck!